# SWIFT checking if a string begins with something but the second character can be anything

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I'm new to using swift so I'm playing around with it and I'm trying to figure out how to check if a given string begins with the word "hello" though the second letter can be anything it doesn't have to be an E so I could type h0llo and it would still return true is what I'm looking to achieve.

This is the code I have so far however, it is jumbled all over the place from testing, so any help would be necessary at this stage for me. I am only adding the code so that you could understand more what it is im trying to achieve

```
func check(_ givenString: String) -> Bool {
    var newString = givenString

    if newString.count > 2 {
        newString.remove(at: String.Index(encodedOffset: 2))
        if newString.hasPrefix("hello") {
            return true 
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
print(check("h0llo"))
```

Comment: I'd use regex for it.  [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression) & 
[NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/swift-regular-expressions/)

Comment: Alternatively, for the sake of learning, you can check three conditions 1. the length is at least `5` 2. the first letter is `"h"` 3. the substring at range `2...4` is `"llo"`.

Comment: @Sulthan can you give an example perhaps? sorry I'm new to this so just getting my head around a lot

Comment: Not related to your question but `String.Index(encodedOffset: 2)` is wrong. It will only work with regular characters (ascii). Not all Characters can be represented with a single byte. The correct approach is `newString.remove(at: newString.index(newString.startIndex, offsetBy: 2))`. If your intent is to remove the second character you can simply use `index(after:)` method `newString.remove(at:  newString.index(after: newString.startIndex))`

Answer (score 4):

A reasonable solution is to check with Regular Expression

```
func check(_ givenString: String) -> Bool {
    return givenString.range(of: "^h.llo", options: .regularExpression) != nil
}
```

The caret `^` checks for beginning of the string and the dot `.` represents any character.

Comment: this is perfect thank you. I can't right answer you because my account is new but really appreciate this

Comment: @sls96 answers are only for solutions to the original question. Comments are perfect to react to an answer. Also, if this solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the checkmark.